# Xcode Touches Thread 1 Signal sigabrt NS Range Exception

Tags: xcode

I tried to run my touches and this came up in main m. 
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

2014-02-11 11:04:08.088 touches3[357:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Does anyone know what I can do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That means that somewhere on your code you're trying to access a variable in an array that is empty.

This usually happens on conjunction to for loops accessing different variables with a fixed cycle.  Please place breakpoints on your uses of arrays and find the one that is causing trouble.

Comment: Agreed. Or [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) will generally identify the offending line very quickly.